# Gate Threshold @ Id = X Confusion

Tags: mosfet, low-power

Kind of a follow up question to [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/36529/low-threshold-n-channel-mosfet) I asked the other day. So a lot of the parts I'm looking at are listed with Vth at a certain Id. I'm not entirely understanding the graphs so I'm not sure if I wanted my desired Vth to be reached at a bigger or smaller current. For example, there are parts listed as Vth: 600mV @ Id = 1mA and also 600mV @ Id = 250uA.

Could somebody explain how the current influences the gate threshold voltage and what that would mean for low power applications such as mine? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current at which \$V_{GS(th)}\$ is specified is a bit arbitrary, every manufacturer chooses the current at which he wants to specify it. These two are still comaparable, since they mention the same voltage. The 1 mA part has the lower \$V_{GS(th)}\$, because you'll have to go below the 600 mV to get the 250 µA the other one specifies.

Other parts can't be compared as easily. They often mention both different voltages and currents.

Note that \$V_{GS(th)}\$ is the voltage at which the FET *begins* to conduct, and that you need a somewhat higher voltage to get a reasonable current in the order of 1 A. Also note that there's much variation in \$V_{GS(th)}\$. The [FDC855N](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/FD/FDC855N.pdf) has a \$V_{GS(th)}\$ of typically 2 V, but minimum 1 V and maximum 3 V, that's a 3:1 range. Always check both limits. The upper limit to be sure the FET is on at a minimum for a high level on the gate, the lower limit to be sure the FET will be off at the maximum for a low level.

Comment: So if I'm at say, 1V for both, the one rated at 250uA will have less current than the one rated at 1mA even though I'm well above the Vth for both?

Comment: @JGord - Yes, but once you're a few 100 of mV above threshold it goes fast, and there won't be much difference. Check fig. 5 on page 3 of the FDC855N datasheet. Threshold about 2.5 V at 25 °C. At 3 V already 2 A, and at 3.5 V you'll have typically 10 A. The threshold is mainly relevant for the minimum gate voltage you have at your disposal. With a 3.3 V supply in worst case conditions you may not get that 5 A for that motor yet.